# Creating a simple slider in javaFX

Tags: javafx, slider, type-conversion

What i am trying to achieve is to create a method next to the initialize method, that can handle the current value of a slidebar. I want that method to pass back the value into a Timeline. The problem i am facing is that the method that handles the slider and when its changing is a void method, but i need that value in double type.

I am having hard time understanding the concept of addlistener and what the difference is between Observable, ObservableValue, InvalidationListener, and ChangeListener.

```
/*DATA FIELD*/

private double cycle;
private Timeline loop;

@FXML
private Slider slider1;


/*METHODS*/

@FXML
public double frequency(){
slider1.valueProperty().addListener(new InvalidationListener(){

@Override
public void invalidated(Observable observable){
cycle = slider1.setValue(slider1.getValue());
}});
return cycle;

public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
slider1 = new Slider(100, 3000, 500);
loop = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(cycle), (ActionEvent event) -> {
        gb.nextGen(gb.getBoard());
        graphic.draw(gb.getBoard());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A good way to do this is using property bindings instead. You could bind the value of your slider, to update any other field. An example to bind your slider to a label:

```
@FXML
private Label label;

@FXML
private Slider slider;

@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
    label.textProperty().bindBidirectional(slider.valueProperty(), new NumberStringConverter());
}
```

And in your concrete case, you could bind it to a double property. You could do something as the following:

```
private final DoubleProperty doubleProperty = new SimpleDoubleProperty();

@FXML
private Slider slider;

@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
    doubleProperty.bind(slider.valueProperty());
    //When you're in need to pass the primitive forward, get it from the property
    doubleProperty.get();
}
```

The binding basically does the following: change the slider, change whatever it's bound to. When using bidirectional binding, it goes both ways. E.g. bind a slider to a textfield, both update each other.